# Checking if object is not of type in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I need to check if an object is not of a certain type. I know in Kotlin it's possible to check if a type is not by using `!is`. I was wondering if there was an equivalent in Swift, or a workaround I could use if it's not possible?

Example in Kotlin:

Assume animals is an interface of different animals and there are classes that implement it such as `Cat`, `Dog`, `Horse`, `Spider`, etc:

```
var animals = listOf<Animals>(Horse(), Cat(), Dog(), Spider())
var chosenAnimals = animals.filter { it !is Spider }
```

Comment: What is the usecase of this?

Comment: When opening a ViewController from a notification, I only need it to do a certain function if the `visibleViewController` it's not of type `MessageViewController`, potentially:  

`if (navigationController?.visibleViewController !is MessageViewController) { 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileVC, animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: false)
}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using swift syntax this is one way to do this

```
let animals: [Animals] = [Horse(), Cat(), Dog(), Spider()]
var chosenAnimals = animals.filter { type(of: $0) != Spider.self }
```

alternatively

```
var chosenAnimals = animals.filter { !($0 is Spider) }
```

Comment: @nielsbot, yes but with the negation. Thanks

Comment: Right. See my answer :)

Comment: So basically wrapping the check with a negation. Okay, easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: or use mutating method `removeAll { $0 is Spider }`

Comment: For me, only the alternative worked. Perhaps because of type casting.

Comment: !!!: `type(of: $0) != Spider.self` is not equivalent to `!($0 is Spider)` if `$0` is an instance of Spider's subclass.

Answer (score 4):

Or, you can create your own isNot function, like this:

```
extension Animal {
    func isNot<T: Animal>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool {
        return !(self is T)
    }
}

print(Horse().isNot(Fish.self)) // prints true
print(Horse().isNot(Horse.self)) // prints false
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent in Swift, but its counterpart is the `is` operator. You only need to negate the operator result.

```
var animals = listOf<Animals>(Horse(), Cat(), Dog(), Spider())
var chosenAnimals = animals.filter { !($0 is Spider) }
```

Or, as you're using a mutating collection (`var`), you could use `removeAll(where:)` to remove all `Spider` instances to solve your problem.

```
var animals = listOf<Animals>(Horse(), Cat(), Dog(), Spider())
animals.removeAll { $0 is Spider } // animals.removeAll(where: { $0 is Spider })
print("Animals: \(animals)") // should not contain Spider instances
```

Comment: you can always use Swift trailing closure syntax as well `animals.removeAll { $0 is Spider }`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
var chosenAnimals = animals.filter({!($0 is Spider)})
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry, I copied @user2759839's question above and almost didn't notice use of `val` instead of `var`. thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working sample in Swift:

```
protocol Animal { }

class Horse : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Spider : Animal { }

let animals:[Animal] = [Horse(), Cat(), Dog(), Spider()]
let chosen = animals.filter { !($0 is Spider) }
```

Fill in your protocols/classes however you like :)